# Header Enricher for spring xd to call http-client t pass headers

Tags: spring-xd

I am using http header enricher component to pass the headers but I am not able to  make a http request using http-client

I have a stream like below I am trying to make a http rest Post request and log it to the logger.I have a API-Key header  for which I used this below header enricher module
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules/tree/master/header-enricher

```
stream create --name test24 --definition "http  |header-enricher  --headers={\"Api-Key\":\"'xyz'\"}| http-client  --url='''http://xyz:/abc''' --httpMethod=POST | log " --deploy

http post --data '{"profileReferenceID":"pPPpe85Ht91e%2FpCvlkJMkniwiM%2BGvPjATkjc6HGqaJFS065txVj%2BhqDPsHz54KEm1RrCXftjNCSl2fpBKKKdrie9n6t9jetWhk29ELCmbw0%3D","templateURL":{"type":"type","href":"/content/notification/templates/EOSWEL?firstName=Abcd&userName=dddd&accountLast=2144&phone=1234&SvcgLOBCd=MS","method":"POST"}}'
> POST (text/plain;Charset=UTF-8) http://localhost:9000 {"profileReferenceID":"pPPpe85Ht91e%2FpCvlkJMkniwiM%2BGvPjATkjc6HGqaJFS065txVj%2BhqDPsHz54KEm1RrCXftjNCSl2fpBKKKdrie9n6t9jetWhk29ELCmbw0%3D","templateURL":{"type":"type","href":"/content/notification/templates/EOSWEL?firstName=Abcd&userName=dddd&accountLast=2144&phone=1234&SvcgLOBCd=MS","method":"POST"}}

2015-11-16T13:05:24-0600 1.2.1.RELEASE WARN xdbus.test24.1-1 retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer - Retries exhausted for message (Body:'{"profileReferenceID":"pPPpe85Ht91e%2FpCvlkJMkniwiM%2BGvPjATkjc6HGqaJFS065txVj%2BhqDPsHz54KEm1RrCXftjNCSl2fpBKKKdrie9n6t9jetWhk29ELCmbw0%3D","templateURL":{"type":"type","href":"/content/notification/templates/EOSWEL?firstName=Abcd&userName=dddd&accountLast=2144&phone=1234&SvcgLOBCd=MS","method":"POST"}}'MessageProperties [headers={requestMethod=POST, User-Agent=Java/1.8.0_60, Host=localhost:9000, Content-Length=305, contentType=text/plain, Api-Key=xyz, requestPath=/, originalContentType=text/plain;Charset=UTF-8}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.test24.1, deliveryTag=2, messageCount=0])
```

I am getting 403 forbidden  i get this error  from my webservice if  my client api key is not passed  which i  was able to reproduce in post man .So I assume my API-Key header is not passed.

```
caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://xyx/abc]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:410) ~[spring-integration-http-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:287) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your `Api-Key` header to be mapped to the HTTP request header:

```
http-client  --url='''http://xyz:/abc''' --httpMethod=POST --mappedRequestHeaders=HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,Api-Key
```

> mappedRequestHeaders
>
> ```
> request message header names to be propagated to/from the adpater/gateway (String, default: HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS)
> ```

Where `HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS` is a set of only standard HTTP headers which are appropriate for request.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#http-client

Comment: You also need to be sure the bus passes the headers. The rabbit and local bus passes all headers; for redis and kafka you have to configure the bus. Or, you can make a composite module containing the header enricher and http client.

Comment: The WARN in the end of stream works shows that this header passes. `MessageProperties` and `retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` - so, looks like `rabbit` bus.

Comment: I can see the headers but X-Api-Key is getting passed i can see in wireshark hence it still fails

Comment: OK. Well, there is no choice unless modify `http-client.xml` module and specify `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` with the `userDefinedHeaderPrefix` to `""`. Just because this option isn't exposed as a module property on the XD.